# Black screen after failed restore - G5

Tags: hardware, powerpc, macos, power-mac

I tried to restore a G5, something went wrong and now I have this at startup:

```
dyld: library not loaded: /usr/liblibconv.2.dylib
Referenced from /bin/sh
Reason: Incompatible library version: sh requires version 7.0.0 or later, but      libiconv.2.dylibprovides version 5.0.0
```

Can anyone help please?

I don't have a Tiger cd as I was restoring using Disk Utility.  I;ve tried various methods for booting from USB but the G5 doesn't seem to give them any power at boot.

Comment: Where exactly is this error showing? Does a black screen with it show up on boot?

Comment: @SoFly it's at boot. An apple logo displays then immediately after this. It goes no further until the fans go into tornado mode and I power off

Comment: What disk did you use when you tried to restore it? Or how did you try to restore it?

Comment: I used a dmg and disk utility. I swapped over the DVD drive and have now installed orig osx again. Phew

Comment: Yeah, sounded like a bad image or install to me, but wanted to verify that you were using the correct media to install the OS on the correct arch.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution to my problem was somewhat messy.

The black screen I mentioned was a result of a failed osx restore. It failed because of a bad dmg. The machine then suffered a kernel panic and I guess it was unable to roll back te changes it had made.

I removed some ugly looking ram and cleaned te others, reinstalled osx from disk using a new drive and have so far not experienced any problems.

Problem caused by dodgy dmg installation and dodgier ram